# c++ call outside class functions

Tags: c++, class, call

Is there an way for an Inside class to call the Outside class functions directly?
Instead of having to check if a boolean is true or not.

Like this:

Inside Class

```
class Inside {

public:
    Inside()
    {
    }
    ~Inside()
    {
    }

    Update()
    {
        if(buttonpress)
        {
         //call Outside::LoadGame();
        }
    }

}
```

Outside Class

```
class Outside {

public:
   Outside();
   ~Outside();
   void LoadGame()
   {
     //Load Game
   }

   Inside* insideObject;

   void Update()
   {
     insideObject->Update();
   }


}
```

Comment: pass outside* as Update parameter

Comment: Question is not clear, please be more descriptive.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Are you talking about inheritage?

Comment: What is exact problem you are trying to solve? For now it looks like a class design flaw. Maybe you want to call `Outside::LoadGame()` in `Outside::Update()` directly?

Comment: Trouble with your `Inside` is that it's not really *inside* `Outside`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for you to do, not without the `Inside::Update` function having a reference to an `Outside` object.

The easiest solution is to call `Update` passing `this` as argument:

```
class Inside
{
    ...

    void Update(Outside* outside)
    {
        outside->LoadGame();
    }
};

// ...

void Outside::Update()
{
    inside->Update(this);
}
```

Another solution is passing `this` as an argument to the constructor when creating the `inside` object in the `Outside` class.

---

However, this couples the two classes very tightly, which can be a sign of bad design. Before you implement this, you should ask yourself "Do I *really* need this tight coupling? Can there be other ways of solving the problem with better design? And what *is* the problem I try to solve anyway?"

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for. Didnt know you could pass "this" as a parameter.

Comment: @SundayBrowsing `this` is a variable (actually, it's a hidden first argument to non-static member functions) just like any other, you just don't have to declare it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to a static method:

**file Outside.h**

```
class Outside {
public:
  static void startGame();
}
```

**file Inside.h**

```
#include "Outside.h"

class Inside {
public:
  void update() { Outside::startGame(); }
}
```

Instead, if you want to access specific instance, you have:

**file Outside.h**

```
class Outside {
public:
  void startGame();
}
```

**file Inside.h v1**

```
#include "Outside.h"

class Inside {
public:
   void update() { o.startGame(); }
private:
   Outside o;
}
```

**file Inside.h v2**

```
#include "Outside.h"

class Inside {
public:
   void update(const Outside& o) { o.startGame(); }
}
```

**Your** specific case:

```
class Inside {
public:
    Inside() { }
    ~Inside(){ }
    Update(Outside* o) {
        if(buttonpress) {
           o->LoadGame();
        }
    }
}

class Outside {
public:
   Outside();
   ~Outside();
   void LoadGame() { }
   Inside* insideObject;
   void Update() {
     insideObject->Update(this);
   }
}
```